# how to change the values of specific rows for specifc columns, with the values of specific rows in the same dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd


       dt = pd.DataFrame({'id_resp':[1,2,3,4,1,2],
                       'country':['a','a','a','a','b','b'],
                       'variable_1':[0,0,0,0,4,8],
                       'variable_2': [2, 3, 4, 5, 14, 18],
                       'variable3': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]})
```

I would like to change the values of the `variable_1` and `variable_2` for the `id_resp`s in `country` `a` that are also in `country` `b`, with the values of the `variable_1` and `variable_2` respectively of the `id_resp`s that are in country b

My resulting dataframe should like

```
  dt_f = pd.DataFrame({'id_resp':[1,2,3,4,1,2],
                           'country':['a','a','a','a','b','b'],
                           'variable_1':[4,8,0,0,4,8],
                           'variable_2': [14, 18, 4, 5, 14, 18],
                           'variable3': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]})
```

Is there a pythonic way of doing that (also selection the `variable_1` and `variable_2` using a `regex`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join ony be filtered rows, then replace missing values by original by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), get columns by original data and last convertm types by original by [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) with [`DataFrame.dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html):

```
df1 = dt[dt['country'].eq('b')]
df = (dt.merge(df1, on='id_resp', how='left', suffixes=('_',''))
        .fillna(dt)[dt.columns]
        .astype(dt.dtypes))
print (df)
   id_resp country  variable_1  variable_2
0        1       b           4          14
1        2       b           8          18
2        3       a           0           4
3        4       a           0           5
4        1       b           4          14
5        2       b           8          18
```

EDIT: If want filter only some columns with regex one possible solution with [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), also is necessary add `id_resp` with selected columns:

```
dt = pd.DataFrame({'id_resp':[1,2,3,4,1,2],
                       'country':['a','a','a','a','b','b'],
                       'variable_1':[0,0,0,0,4,8],
                       'variable_2': [2, 3, 4, 5, 14, 18],
                       'variable3': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]})


df1 = dt[dt['country'].eq('b')].filter(regex='^variable_|id_resp')
print (df1)
   id_resp  variable_1  variable_2
4        1           4          14
5        2           8          18

df = (dt.merge(df1, on='id_resp', how='left', suffixes=('_',''))
        .fillna(dt)[dt.columns]
        .astype(dt.dtypes))
print (df)
   id_resp country  variable_1  variable_2  variable3
0        1       a           4          14          1
1        2       a           8          18          1
2        3       a           0           4          1
3        4       a           0           5          1
4        1       b           4          14          2
5        2       b           8          18          2
```

Comment: is there a way to select the variables/columns of interest (in this toy example `variable_1` & `variable_2`) via a regex expression ?

Comment: @quant - What are rules for select?

Comment: I updated the question. So in this case the regex would be `^variable_`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method using `unstack` and `np.where`

```
dt = dt.set_index(['id_resp','country'])
m = dt.unstack().swaplevel(axis=1)
c = m.loc[:,'b'].notna().any(1)
m.loc[:,'a'] = np.where(c[:,None],m.loc[:,'b'],m.loc[:,'a'])
```

---

```
dt = m.stack(0).reindex(dt.index).reset_index()
print(dt)
   id_resp country  variable_1  variable_2
0        1       a         4.0        14.0
1        2       a         8.0        18.0
2        3       a         0.0         4.0
3        4       a         0.0         5.0
4        1       b         4.0        14.0
5        2       b         8.0        18.0
```